# Concatenar string com int no printf

Tags: c, string, printf

É possível fazer isto em C:

```
int MAX = 30;

printf("\n| %".MAX."s | %8s | %8s |", "Nome", "Salario", "Idade");
printf("\n| %".MAX."s | %8.2f | %8d |", pessoa[i].nome, pessoa[i].salario, pessoa[i].idade);
```

Notem o `MAX` entre as *strings* para delimitar o alinhamento.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sim é possível:

```
printf("\n| %.*s | %8s | %8s |", MAX, "Nome", "Salario", "Idade");
```

O segredo é o `.*`. Ele é um parâmetro para a *string* de formatação. Note que como é o primeiro parâmetro o `MAX` precisa ser o primeiro da lista, ou seja, segue a mesma lógica dos outros parâmetros normais do `printf()`. Com o `.*` ele é um limitador do máximo de caracteres que serão exibidos que é o que eu entendi que você deseja. Ainda coloquei opções para que use o parâmetro como o mínimo de caracteres que deve ser apresentado usando apenas o `*`.

Leia a [documentação](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fprintf) para mais detalhes. Especialmente sobre o "The field width". E um [sumário](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/printf/) sobre os parâmetros de formatação existentes.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    int max = 30;
    printf("\n| %*s | %8s | %8s |", max, "Nome", "Salario", "Idade");
    printf("\n| %.*s | %8s | %8s |", max, "Nome", "Salario", "Idade");
    max = 3;
    printf("\n| %*s | %8s | %8s |", max, "Nome", "Salario", "Idade");
    printf("\n| %.*s | %8s | %8s |", max, "Nome", "Salario", "Idade");
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/hT8Qsl). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/fqrzoxeo-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/Library/PrintFormat.c).

Comment: Dessa forma ele imprime "Nome" com o limite de MAX caracteres?

Comment: Exato. É apenas um limite.

Comment: Obrigado Bigown, era exatamente isto minha necessidade. fora de grande ajuda